# FreeCodeCamp JSON code isn't working

Tags: javascript, json

Instructions:

> Write a function which takes an id, a property (prop), and a value.
>   For the given id in collection: If value is non-blank (value !== "")
>   and prop is not "tracks" then update or set the value for the prop. If
>   the prop is "tracks" and value is non-blank, push the value onto the
>   end of the tracks array. If value is blank, delete that prop. Always
>   return the entire collection object.

Code that's working:

```
function update(id, prop, value) {
    if (prop === "tracks" && value !== "") {
        collection[id][prop].push(value);
    } else if (value !== "") {
        collection[id][prop] = value;
    } else {
        delete collection[id][prop];
    }
    return collection;
}
```

My code, that's not working:

```
function update(id, prop, value) {
    if (value !== "" && prop !== "tracks") {
        collection[id][prop] = value;
    } else if (value !== "" && prop === "tracks") {
        collection[id][prop].push(value);
    } else if(value === "") {
        delete collection[id][prop];
    } else {
        return collection;
    }
}
```

The entire code:

```
// Setup
var collection = {
    2548 : {
        album : "Slippery When Wet",
        artist : "Bon Jovi",
        tracks : [ 
            "Let It Rock", 
            "You Give Love a Bad Name" 
        ]
    },
    2468 : {
        album : "1999",
        artist : "Prince",
        tracks : [ 
            "1999", 
            "Little Red Corvette" 
        ]
    },
    1245 : {
        artist : "Robert Palmer",
        tracks : [ ]
    },
    5439: {
        album : "ABBA Gold"
    }
};
// Keep a copy of the collection for tests
var collectionCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(collection));

// Only change code below this line
function update(id, prop, value) {
    if (prop === "tracks" && value !== "") {
        collection[id][prop].push(value);
    } else if (value !== ""){
        collection[id][prop] = value;
    } else {
        delete collection[id][prop];
    }

    return collection;
}
// Alter values below to test your code
update(5439, "artist", "ABBA");
```

I followed all the instructions. But why isn't my code working? And why the other one is working?

Comment: _“I followed all the instructions”_ – no, you did not – you failed on this last part: _“**Always** return the entire collection object.”_

Comment: else{
    return collection;
  }
...I thought, I did. @CBroe

Comment: And in which cases is that branch actually reached? Play it through (on paper if you have to), with all four possible combinations for the two variables! // Aside from that, returning the collection resp. demanding it be returned doesn’t actually make that much sense here to begin with – the collection is not passed to the function (either yours or the working example mentioned), but defined in a higher scope – so returning it doesn’t actually achieve much here.

Answer (score 0):

The instructions say this :

> Always return the entire collection object.

Yet, you only return it if neither of the else statements are true... which is never!

So, you need to change ...

```
function update(id, prop, value) {
    if (value !== "" && prop !== "tracks") {
        collection[id][prop] = value;
    } else if (value !== "" && prop === "tracks") {
        collection[id][prop].push(value);
    } else if(value === "") {
        delete collection[id][prop];
    } else {
        return collection;
    }
}
```

... into ...

```
function update(id, prop, value) {
    if (value !== "" && prop !== "tracks") {
        collection[id][prop] = value;
    } else if (value !== "" && prop === "tracks") {
        collection[id][prop].push(value);
    } else if(value === "") {
        delete collection[id][prop];
    }
    return collection;
}
```

---

#### Note

A better way to achieve the exact same effect, would be to do this :

```
function update(id, prop, value) {
    if (value === "") {
        delete collection[id][prop];
    } else if (prop === "tracks") {
        collection[id][prop].push(value);
    } else {
        collection[id][prop] = value;
    }
    return collection;
}
```

Comment: @Anontu : The rest of the code looks does seem to (1) match the criteria mentioned in the instructions and (2) does produce the expected results when I run the code in a Fiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/38929b5L/1/). You can, however, still add a few optimalizations. See the note at the bottom of my answer.

Comment: Wow...so that's what good coding is. God knows how long I will take to reach that level...
Thank you. @John Slegers

Comment: @Anontu : It's not as hard as it seems. You'll get there sooner than you think.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and the i create a property with empty array and next use .push() to append the value. And Voilá. Here my code below:

```
function updateRecords(id, prop, value) {

if (prop !== "tracks" && value !== "") {
    collection[id][prop] = value; 
  } else if (prop === "tracks" && value !== "") {
      if(!collection[id].hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
        collection[id][prop] = []; //Create a property with empty array
        collection[id][prop].push(value); //Append a value into the array 
      } else {
         collection[id][prop].push(value); //Append a value into the exist property array
      }
  } else if (value === "") {
     delete collection[id][prop];
  }
  return collection;
}
```